# Plotting multiple lines in one graph with pandas and matplotlib, using climate data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, anaconda

I'm trying to create a graph that shows whether or not average temperatures in my city are increasing. I'm using data provided by NOAA and have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
            DATE  TAVG  MONTH  YEAR
    0    1939-07  86.0  07     1939
    1    1939-08  84.8  08     1939
    2    1939-09  82.2  09     1939
    3    1939-10  68.0  10     1939
    4    1939-11  53.1  11     1939
    5    1939-12  52.5  12     1939
```

This is saved in a variable called "avgs", and I then use groupby and plot functions like so:

```
    avgs.groupby(["YEAR"]).plot(kind='line',x='MONTH', y='TAVG')
```

This produces a line graph (see below for example) for each year that shows the average temperature for each month. That's great stuff, but I'd like to be able to put all of the yearly line graphs into one graph, for the purposes of visual comparison (to see if the monthly averages are increasing).

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxIN7.png)

I'm a total noob with matplotlib and pandas, so I don't know the best way to do this. Am I going wrong somewhere and just don't realize it? And if I'm on the right track, where should I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to the other answer (by Anake), but you can get control over legend here (the other answer, legends for all years will be "TAVG". I add a new year entries into your data just to show this.

```
avgs = '''
          DATE  TAVG  MONTH  YEAR
    0    1939-07  86.0  07     1939
    1    1939-08  84.8  08     1939
    2    1939-09  82.2  09     1939
    3    1939-10  68.0  10     1939
    4    1940-11  53.1  11     1940
    5    1940-12  52.5  12     1940
'''


ax = plt.subplot()
for key, group in avgs.groupby("YEAR"):
    ax.plot(group.MONTH, group.TAVG, label = key)
ax.set_xlabel('Month')
ax.set_ylabel('TAVG')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

will result in

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
ax = None
for group in df.groupby("YEAR"):
    ax = group[1].plot(x="MONTH", y="TAVG", ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

Each `plot()` returns the matplotlib Axes instance where it drew the plot. So by feeding that back in each time, you can repeatedly draw on the same set of axes.

I don't think you can do that directly in the functional style as you have tried unfortunately.